# VBA code to append data from multiple tables in multiple workbooks into data model

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code that will append data from multiple tables in multiple workbooks into data model in the active workbook

please help

Comment: Don't think it's possible to interact with the DataModel from VBA so the fastest way to achieve this is PowerQuery. If the files are static (filenames don't change) you can setup the queries manually once. if you have to many of them you could use a simple vba script to import the location/fileNames and than load this as a table to Powerquery (Data > from table range). From their you can dynamically populate and append.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you put the data into the data model? With ``Power Pivot`` you can connect directly to different sources and refresh them when you want. You can add a table to the data model by recording a macro. First, select the table then in ``Power Pivot`` ribbon tab select ``Add to Data Model``.